# How to order text file columns python?

Tags: python, text-files

My code in python is

```
file.write("Name\t Age\t M/F\t")
file.write("Mo\t 15\t M\t")
```

yet it comes out

```
Name   Age  M/F
Mo 15 M
```

The columns are not in line as in they are all not in the same column. Is there a command to sort it out so it saves and prints in one column and line?

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the error? I don't fully get what "not in line" means. Also, please use the code formatting tools provided by SO; I took care of it this time.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about string formatting (check the [string format documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)). You can do the following:

```
fmt = '{0:10s}{1:10s}{2:10s}'
file.write(fmt.format('Name', 'Age', 'M/F'))
file.write(fmt.format('Mo', '15', 'M'))
# Name      Age       M/F       
# Mo        15        M
```

In the format `{0:10s}`, the `s` means that the variable you want to write is a string and the `10` means that you want the output to be 10 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatstrings) with a specification of how many chars the entry should have: `{:10s}` for 10 chars.

Here is an example:

```
with open('name.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('{:10s}{:10s}{:10s}\n'.format('Name', 'Age', 'M/F'))
    file.write('{:10s}{:10s}{:10s}\n'.format('Mo', '15', 'M'))
```

leading to

```
Name      Age       M/F       
Mo        15        M
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
file=open("test.txt","wb")
file.write("Name\t Age\t M/F\t")
file.write("Mo\t 15\t M\t")
file.close()
```

and Got

```
Name     Age     M/F    Mo   15  M
```

because as for windows you need \r\n for new line
but that was the only problem.

with

```
file=open("test.txt","w")
file.write("Name\t Age\t M/F\n")
file.write("Mo\t 15\t M")
file.close()
```

output in file was was

```
Name     Age     M/F
Mo       15      M
```

So the code is working on Linux and windows dude.

What are you running it on anyway?

Comment: Different tab stop size maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with python string formating.

```
fmt = '{0:<30} {1:<10} {2:<10}'

file.write(fmt.format("Name","Age","M/F"))
file.write(fmt.format("Mo","15","M"))
```

Output:

```
Name                           Age        M/F       
Mo                             15         M
```